# Refactoring out a toolbar to another file

Tags: swift, swiftui

Experienced Swift UIKit coder but definitely not with SwiftUI. Let's say I have the following code:

```
HStack {
    Button(
        action: { self.createNode() },
        label: {
            Text("ADD").bold().font(.system(size: 40)).frame(width: 200, height: 80).background(Color.yellow).cornerRadius(5)
    })
    Spacer()
    Button(
        action: { self.deleteNode() },
        label: {
            Text("DELETE").bold().font(.system(size: 40)).frame(width: 200, height: 80).background(Color.yellow).cornerRadius(5)
    })
}
```

A *very* simple toolbar. But now, let's add (a) four more `Buttons` and fit this into a "root" view. Makes for what in UIKit we call a *massive view controller*.

I'm trying to move this entire `HStack` out of the root view, but I'm having issues with the `action`. I'm aware I can create `ViewModifiers`, custom views, and - at least to some degree - move some things into extensions. But I haven't been able to move this extension "lock, stock, and barrel" anywhere else. I'm stuck trying to move `createNode()` and `deleteNode()` anywhere else.

I'm sure it's me trying to fit a square peg (`UIKit`) into a round hole (`SwiftUI`), but none of the WWDC sessions or other resources I've found seem to be pointing me in the right direction. What am I missing?

EDIT:

Here's what the two actions are - they work properly.

```
@State var nodes: [Node] = []

func createNode() {
    let newNodeName = nodes.count + 1
    let newNode = Node(name: newNodeName)
    nodes.append(newNode)
}
func deleteNode() {
    if nodes.count != 0 {
        nodes.remove(at: nodes.count - 1)
    }
}
```

My question **is not** about Swift, or about maintaining the array. It's about SwiftUI, and how to "refactor" my current 140 line file into smaller things - in this case by removing the "top bar" HStack into it's own file in Xcode.

This horizontal stack of Buttons will eventually number 5 (it's an iPad only app) and my issue is how to move the Button "actions", type `() -> Void` correctly.

More, here's a simplified view of the entire file (forgive the markdown use, I couldn't find a better way to represent this):

```
HStack    
    VStack
       HStack  <-- Contains the Buttons that add/delete the nodes
       HStack
       HStack  <-- Contains the nodes themselves, will soon contain thumbnails    
    List
```

If my HStack consists of a horizontal row of `Text` views, it works fine. But when I try to move a `Button` (be it nested in an HStack or standalone) into a separate file, I get build issues.

Comment: What are `createdNode`/`deleteNode` supposed to do?

Comment: I believe it's irrelevant to the question, but I'll edit it to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest refactoring actions and `@State` into a view model.

```swift
final class ViewModel: BindableObject {

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var nodes: [Node] = [] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(())
        }
    }

    func createNode() {
        let newNodeName = nodes.count + 1
        let newNode = Node(name: newNodeName)
        nodes.append(newNode)
    }

    func deleteNode() {
        if nodes.count != 0 {
            nodes.remove(at: nodes.count - 1)
        }
    }

}
```

All the views that need access to the actions, need to declare this property:

```swift
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
```

More info about `@EnvironmentObject` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject).

Whenever the nodes changes, all subviews that declare the environment object will be redrawn.

You only need to set the environment object in the container view, for it to be passed down all the subviews.

e.g.

```swift
ContentView().environmentObject(ViewModel())
```

---

**Your view hierarchy**:

```
HStack    
    VStack
       HStack  <- @EnvironmentObject (will call the actions)
       HStack
       HStack  <- @EnvironmentObject (will use viewModel.nodes to display nodes)
    List
```

Comment: Looks like I was wrong - it *is* a Swift issue! I'm working through what is now a SIGABRT in SceneDelegate when I'm trying to instantiate the `EnvironmentObject`. (I'm also digging deeper into that @ type and Combine... a paradigm shift it is. Once I work through things, expect an accepted answer. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction - that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: For more about property wrapper and $ variables, see [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-delegates.md) Swift evolution post.

Comment: Again, thanks. I'm truly using an iOS "single view" app so my Single Source of Truth is the canned `ContentView`. For now I decided that an `@EnvironmentObject` was overkill and decided to go with a simple `@State` and `@Binding`. I learn best by "hands-on" and you starred me to do some digging on things I needed to learn. I'll consider the @EnvironmentObject if I think it's the right route to go. (I'm old school and want my variable scope to be as limited as possible.)